# Silverlight 5 - Out-of-Browser Window Positioning

Tags: position, silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I have a method which saves my main window's position using isolated storage. Another method is responsible for loading the position. Easy. I call the "save" when closing the main window and the "load" when opening the window. Easy

But when the saved postion is applied to the newly opening window, I see the window appear briefly in the default position before it is relocated to the desired saved postion. This is annoying. Any idea on how to prevent that?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I Think it should help you more

1 . **Click On Sliverlight Project**

2 . **Select Properties option**

3 . **Select First tab option Like Silverlight**

4 . **Click On Out-Of-Browser setting Option**

5 . **Set the window size, window title or window position etc......**